# Preview in BigSur

Tags: preview

I have a  problem with Preview.
I have an image A.jpg, I make a rotation and "Save As" (with ALT key) as A-rotate.jpg.
Quit Preview, go to Finder.
Reopen A.jpg is rotated and A-rotate.jpg too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preview, like Pages, Numbers, TextEdit and other Apple apps -- automatically saves any changes you make to a document. It does this when you close the file, but it can happen just after modification.

What you have done is to modify `A.jpg`, then save it as another file `A-rotate.jpg`, -- then you closed `A.jpg`, **at which point Preview will automatically save your changes**.

What you need to do is to **Duplicate** `A.jpg` (under the File menu) BEFORE you make the changes, and then save that duplicate as `A-rotate.jpg`.

You should try to think that editing a document alters it on the disk. You're not just editing some temporary cached version in RAM.

There is a setting in **System Preferences > General** to *"Ask to keep changes when closing documents"*, which will stop the behaviour.

Comment: "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" did nothing… with a reboot too.

Comment: Retry and it's work…